# Using zxing on Windows7 and JAVA 64bit

Tags: java, zxing, qr-code, javac

can anyone guide me on how I can use zxing for a little java tool I'd like to write.

I was starting here:
https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Getting-Started-Developing

Then I moved to:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/

The problem is I do not know which package to download!

What are these folders for?

```
android-core/                                      15-Feb-2015 13:05                   
android-integration/                               15-Feb-2015 13:05                   
core/                                              15-Feb-2015 13:05                   
glass-mirror/                                      02-Dec-2013 11:10                   
javase/                                            15-Feb-2015 13:05                            
zxing-parent/                                      15-Feb-2015 13:05                   
zxing.appspot.com/                                 15-Feb-2015 13:05                         
zxingorg/                                          15-Feb-2015 13:05
```

I guessed and tried the folder **zxingorg/3.2.0/**

But there are two jar files.

```
 zxingorg-3.2.0-javadoc.jar
 zxingorg-3.2.0-sources.jar
```

Which one is the right one?

I tried **zxingorg-3.2.0-javadoc.jar**. 
I put this file in the same folder that also contains my **qrtest.java** file.

I opened a command window moved to that folder and wrote:

```
javac -cp zxingorg-3.2.0-javadoc.jar qrtest.java
```

Unfortunately I get:

```
qrtest.java:11: error: package com.google.zxing does not exist
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
```

So, where is the mistake I made?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing a Java desktop application you only need **core** and **javase** modules.

**zxingorg** is a web application. The app behind http://zxing.org.

If you use Maven, include the following in your *pom.xml*:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>${com.google.zxing.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
        <version>${com.google.zxing.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Were `com.google.zxing.version` is the desired zxing version. I recommend 3.2.0.

If not using maven, just download the jars and add them as dependencies.

[core](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/3.2.0/core-3.2.0.jar)
[core-javadoc](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/3.2.0/core-3.2.0-javadoc.jar)
[javase](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/javase/3.2.0/javase-3.2.0.jar)
[javase-javadoc](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/javase/3.2.0/javase-3.2.0-javadoc.jar)

After that you're going to be able to proceed with your first steps with the library.

For further reference you can also download the sources.

[core-src](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/3.2.0/core-3.2.0-sources.jar)
[javase-src](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/javase/3.2.0/javase-3.2.0-sources.jar)

An example of what you're going to be able to do is [CommandLineRunner.java](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/javase/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/j2se/CommandLineRunner.java) (which is part of **javase** module)